# Does replacing social media use with solitary activities alleviate loneliness?

Tags: depression, stress, social-networks, social

Many studies about problematic social media use have suggested that social media [increases loneliness.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S073658532030215X) The typical hypothesis given is that social media displaces time spent in face-to-face social interactions. I cannot help but wonder:

Would engaging in solitary constructive activities (e.g. reading, art) provide a decrease in loneliness compared to using social media? In other words, could even solitary behaviours -- rather than face-to-face interactions -- provide a decrease in loneliness, when they replace the use of social media?

Comment: You are still participating in lone activities aren't you. When using social media you are not **with** anyone. You are alone on your device communicating through the computer or mobile phone. Engaging in solitary activities, you are still alone. How could that possibly decrease loneliness?

Comment: Well, one example is that some studies suggest meaning can alleviate loneliness. So, from this point of view, generating meaning via such solitary activities could indirectly affect loneliness. Another possibility is that social media makes one feel even more lonely by contrasting a person's life with other people's lives. I was thinking of such examples with the question.

Comment: *"some studies suggest meaning can alleviate loneliness"*. That's interesting if they say meaning alone without social context. Could you please provide examples of this for context and question clarity?